# Do you know any open-source free Idea/Suggestion Management tool?

Tags: open-source

I include myself in a group of thinkers in this "small" company. In order to gather suggestions and improvement ideas from my development team members, I was put in charge of mounting an Idea/Suggestion Management system.

Some of the enjoyable features are:

- provide user based (possible anonymous) suggestions mechanism
- provide voting mechanism on suggestions
- (optionally) mechanism to log actions taken to implement the suggestion

Do you use or know any such tool?

Comment: Have you tried http://hunchbuzz.com/idea-management-software-tools/free/ ?

Answer (score 3):

Check out following link

- www.ideatorrent.org/
- www.osqa.net/gallery/
- code.google.com/p/stacked/downloads/list
- alternativeto.net/software/google-moderator/
- www.google.com/moderator/

BTW, I'm thinking about using JIRA for tracking the idea, any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [uservoice.com](https://www.uservoice.com/).

Stackoverflow uses it. Try it out for yourself.

[http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20090219112537/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com:80/)

Comment: SO now uses https://meta.stackoverflow.com for feature suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Pligg](http://www.pligg.com/) that is dig like that u can use to add new idea vote and discuss

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) instance using the [VotePlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/VotePlugin) or [FiveStarVotePlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/FiveStarVotePlugin)? Users could submit tickets as their suggestions, and then use the voting system. Trac would also be able to meet your logging requirement if you configured it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered something like Kluster? http://www.kluster.com/  It has a great interface and is geared right at rating ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using many different software for capturing ideas, uservoice, getsatisfaction e.t.c ... Have you tried http://hunchbuzz.com/idea-management-software-tools/free/ ?